# Is it a good habit to reset self to nullptr when use move-constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

in C++11, the move-constructor/operator support resource/memory move.

This is my example:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : table_(nullptr), alloc_(0) {}
    ~A()
    {
        if (table_)
            delete[] table_;
    }

    A(const A & other)
    {
        // table_ is not initialized
        // if (table_)
        //    delete[] table_;
        table_ = new int[other.alloc_];
        memcpy(table_, other.table_, other.alloc_ * sizeof(int));
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    }
    A& operator=(const A & other)
    {
        if (table_)
            delete[] table_;
        table_ = new int[other.alloc_];
        memcpy(table_, other.table_, other.alloc_ * sizeof(int));
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
        return *this;
    }

    A(A && other)
    {
        // table_ is not initialized in constructor
        // if (table_)
        //    delete[] table_;
        table_ = other.table_;
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    }

    A& operator=(A && other)
    {
        if (table_)
            delete[] table_;
        table_ = other.table_;
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    }

private:
    int *table_;
    int alloc_;
};
```

It seems good, but sometimes I want to move a local variable, like this:

```
class B {
private:
    A a_;

public:
    void hello()
    {
        A tmp;
        // do something to tmp
        a_ = std::move(tmp);
        // tmp.~A() is called, so a_ is invalid now.
    }
};
```

when the function end, `tmp.~A()` will be called, at this time, `a_` and `tmp` has the same `table_` pointer, when `tmp delete[] table_`, `a_'s table_` will be invalid.

I'm wandering when should I use `std::move` to assign tmp to a_, without copy.

with help of the answers, I modify the A's move-constructor like this:

```
class A {
private:
    void reset()
    {
        table_ = nullptr;
        alloc_ = 0;
    }

public:

    A(A && other)
    {
        table_ = other.table_;
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
        other.reset();
    }

    A& operator=(A && other)
    {
        std::swap(table_, other.table_);
        std::swap(alloc_, other.alloc_);
    }
};
```

In this code, when I move something, I will swap new and old reference, so the old `tmp` will delete[] original a_ table_, which is useless.

this is a good habit to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you move from `other` in `A(A && other)`, you should also set to nulltpr its moved data members. So the fixed code should looks as follows:

```
A(A && other)
{
    //if (table_)
    //    delete[] table_; // no need for this in move c-tor
    table_ = other.table_;
    other.table_ = nullptr;
    alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    other.alloc_ = nullptr;
}

A& operator=(A && other)
{
    // as n.m. has pointed out, this move assignment does not 
    // protect against self assignment. One solution is to use
    // swap aproach here. The other is to simply check if table_ == other.table_. 
    // Also see here for drawbacks of swap method:
    // http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html
    delete[] table_;
    table_ = other.table_;
    other.table_ = nullptr;
    alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    other.alloc_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

This puts `other` in what standard calls `valid but unspecified state`.

you may also use std::swap as follows:

```
A(A && other)
{
    table_ = other.table_;
    alloc_ = other.alloc_;
}

A& operator=(A && other)
{
    std::swap(table_, other.table_);
    std::swap(alloc_, other.alloc_);
    return *this;
}
```

this way deallocation will be done when the moved from object is being destroyed.

Comment: yes, I update my question, my solution is the same with yours, is it a good habit to write this kind of `move` function for all class ?

Comment: @zhaochenyou yes, its valid

Comment: @zhaochenyou additionally if you want your class to make use of move semantics in STL containers (ex. vector etc) then make your move copy constructor and assignment operator `noexcept`, otherwise for example vector will use copy-ing instead of moving-ing your objects when for example doing `resize`

Comment: Checking `if (table_)` in a *constructor* is complete craziness.

Comment: That swapping move ctor is still wrong. It's swapping an uninitialized variable.

Comment: `if (table_) delete[] table_;` is redundant.  The delete operator already checks for a null pointer.  Just do `delete[] table_;`.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous problems with this code (even assuming you do want to fiddle with arrays and pointers, which you shouldn't in real life. Just use std::vector).

Bad code:

```
A()
{
    table_ = nullptr;
    alloc_ = 0;
}
```

Don't use assignment in the ctor body, use member-init-lists. Good code:

```
A() : table{nullptr}, alloc_ {0} {}
```

Ditto for other constructors.

---

Redundant code:

```
    if (table_)
        delete[] table_;
```

`delete` is going to check your pointer again. `delete`ing a `nullptr` is perfectly safe. Don't bother.

---

**VERY** bad code:

```
A(const A & other)
{
    if (table_)
        delete[] table_;
```

`table` is not initialized. Accessing it is UB. Moreover, there is no need to do this check in the constructor. There won't be any allocations in a freshly constructed object. Just remove the check. Ditto for other constructors.

---

Bad code:

```
A& operator=(const A & other)
{
    if (table_)
        delete[] table_;
```

Doesn't guard against self-assignment. Ditto for other assignment operators.

---

These are all habits that need to be unlearned whether you code for C++03 or C++11. Now for the move:

```
A(A && other)
{
    if (table_)
        delete[] table_;
    table_ = other.table_;
    alloc_ = other.alloc_;
}
```

This is totally wrong. You need to change the object you are moving **from**, otherwise it's not a move at all but a simple shallow copy.

```
A(A && other) : table_{other.table_}, alloc_{other.alloc_} {
{
   other.table_ = nullptr;
   other.alloc_ = 0;        
}
```

Ditto for the move assignment.

---

`std::swap` in the move ctor is an excellent idiom when you deal with user-defined types. It is not exactly needed for primitive types, mainly because you need to initialize them first and then immediately swap, but you can use it nevertheless.

Comment: now I understand your code, yes, I agree your word, I should modify them

Comment: actually I think your review is very helpful, I will update the example code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your move constructor and assignment operator are effectively performing a shallow-copy. You should set `other.table` to `nullptr`, for the move to make sense in this case. And of course this will avoid undefined behaviour in deleting the same array twice, as you suggest in your example.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative is *swapping* the values in the move constructor.

```
A& operator=(A && other)
{
    using namespace std;
    swap(table_, other.table_);
    swap(alloc_, other.alloc_);
    return *this;
}
```

This way, the contents of the source are placed in the target and the latter's contents get shifted to the source - which then will clean them up correctly when being deleted itself (which is what you expect anyway, otherwise, you would not want to move the object...).

Move constructor can profit from above assignment then:

```
A(A&& other) : A()
{
    *this = std::move(other);
}
```

Comment: UB in the move ctor. An `int` and an `int*` are not going to initialise themselves.

Comment: @n.m. Have a close look: I do constructor forwarding, calling the default constructor!

Comment: ah sorry missed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the move constructor/assignment, after copying the pointer, assign them "nullptr", so that when the destructor gets called, it will be no op.

This how I would go and write the move constructor and assignment. And also, you can avoid "if" check for "delete", if it is "nullptr", it will be no op.

```
    A(A && other)
    {
        delete[] table_;
        table_ = other.table_;
        other.table_ = nullptr;
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    }

    A& operator=(A && other) {
        delete[] table_;
        table_ = other.table_;
        other.table_ = nullptr; // assign the source to be nullptr
        alloc_ = other.alloc_;
        return *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your **move constructor** and **assignment operator** like this:

```
// Simple move constructor
A(A&& arg) : member(std::move(arg.member)) // the expression "arg.member" is lvalue
{} 
// Simple move assignment operator
A& operator=(A&& other) {
     member = std::move(other.member);
     return *this;
}
```

as defined [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)